# How do I understand netstat output?

Tags: networking, netstat

Recently in wondering about my slower-than-usual internet connection, I learned that you can run the `netstat` command line in the command prompt.

However, when I use this it tends to show things like, "cloudfront.net" or various "***.facebook.com" lines.

What does any of this mean? I know the 1e100 is referring to Google and is basically harmless, but I couldn't find any info on the other stuff. Are the others possibly hackers, or just traffic "inquiry", or what?

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) is a content delivery system by Amazon.  You could be visiting a site that is using CloudFront to deliver content.  Similarly you could be visiting another site that is referencing content from facebook.com without seeing facebook.com in your browser's address bar.

The video [Detecting Spyware Using NetStat](http://www.pcmech.com/article/detecting_spyware_using_netstat/) might be helpful.

Comment: You can also use netstat -b 10  .. 10 would be 10 seconds, it repeats the netstat command every 10 seconds, this can sometimes catch malware that does not have a persistent connection. Ctrl+C stops the Netstat interval command. You can use any amount of seconds you wish.